# how to extract keys of nested object in same nested format added by new key to keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am using [react table](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/simple-table), in which I need to provide my api data keys, with added new key Header to create React Table Head (TH > TD);

Below are the sample data getting from API, and I need to pass object keys to table head and object keys to table body. Table head need to keep for common keys.

[To Achieve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is52q.png)

My data sample:

```
{
  'data':
    {
        'id': 486897532,
        'active': null,
        'acc_info': [
        {
          'acc_name': 'saving',
          'bank_info': [
            {
              'bank_name': 'ABC',
              'bank_address': 'address',
            },
            {
              'bank_name': 'DEF',
              'bank_address': 'address',
            }]
        },
        {
            'acc_name': 'FXE',
            'bank_info': [
            {
                'bank_name': 'ABC',
                'bank_address': 'address',
            },
            {
                'bank_name': 'DEF',
                'bank_address': 'address',
            }]
        },
      ],
    },
    {
        'id': 56465945,
        'active': null,
        'acc_info': [
        {
          'acc_name': 'current',
          'bank_info': [
            {
              'bank_name': 'ABC',
              'bank_address': 'address',
            },
            {
              'bank_name': 'DEF',
              'bank_address': 'address',
            }]
        },
        {
            'acc_name': 'FXE',
            'bank_info': [
            {
                'bank_name': 'ABC',
                'bank_address': 'address',
            },
            {
                'bank_name': 'DEF',
                'bank_address': 'address',
            }]
        },
      ],
    }
}
```

and expected result should be:

```
[
  {
    Header: "id"
  },
  {
    Header: "active"
  },
  {
    Header: "acc_info",
    columns: [
    {
       Header: "acc_name",
    },
    {
       Header: "bank_name",
    },
    {
       Header: "bank_address"
    }]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved!!

Those are using or new to React Table here is the steps:

**For Table title**

1. React Table comes with 'columns' props which expects object with
   Header and accessor keys. Header for TH title and accessor for
   accessing concern table body column
2. Use js Map or Ladash _.map to get expected values
3. create object variable with 'Header' & 'accessor' key and mapped data as
   values

Cheers..